# Multiple chains of then on a JS Promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

Today I tried out what happens when I add multiple chains of then to a Promise. My test code looks like that (TypeScript)

```js
class Test {

    private simulateHeavyStuff(time: number){
        // console.log("-"+time+"-");
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        var end = start;
        while(end < start + time) {
            end = new Date().getTime();
        }
    }

    test(): Promise<void> {
        let promise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
        });

        // ##### ADDING CHAIN 1 #####
        promise
        .then(()=>console.log("then1"))
        .then(()=>this.simulateHeavyStuff(2000))
        .then(()=>console.log("then11"))
        .catch(console.error)

        return promise;
    }

}

let t = new Test();

// ##### ADDING CHAIN 2 #####
t.test()
.then(()=>console.log("then2"))
.then(()=>console.log("then21"))
.catch(console.error)
```

**This prints out:**

```
then1
then2
        <---it's pausing here
then21
then11
```

**Can someone explain the determinism behind this behavior?**

I thought it would either print (parallel chains)

```
then1
then2
then21
       <--- I guessed the pause will be here
then11
```

or (one chain)

```
then1
       <--- with the pause here
then11
then2
then21
```

Comment: The callbacks are queued in some order. It's deterministic, but you should not need to care about the order. If it matters, then put your callbacks after each other in a chain. If not, the concurrent chains run at their own speeds and possibly interleaved. In any case, your problem is that `simulateHeavyStuff` is blocking instead of making a promise for an asynchronous result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I guess I understand what happens after some clarifications of Jaromanda X down in the comments!

**It is fully deterministic!**

Promises add the callbacks to the so called "**Microtasks**" stack. Other than other JS stacks those Microtasks run when the JS stack is empty (all synchronous code is done)...see the Video posted by Jaromanda X in the comments!

So it happens like this:

- "then1" is added to the MT Stack
- test() returns
- "then2" is added to the MT Stack

Synchronous code is done! Microtasks time!

The MT Stack looks like this now

```
then1
then2
```

So then1 is run and adds another Microtask to the MT stack as it returns a Promise. The MT stack looks like this now

```
then2
heavyStuff(2000)
```

As further Microtasks are run until the MT stack is empty this goes on until all MTs are finished. Then any other code goes on...

Comment: there is no `race conditions`

Comment: Good point, it's single threaded. I guess the first callback can be started after leaving the test() method or after finishing the outer code... ?!
Edited the answer: what I mean with race condition here

Comment: Ah ok, so when i add multiple chains the first chain elements are called in the same loop, the nth elements are in the same loop as well...?!

Comment: no, I was wrong - well, it doesn't matter ... the tasks added to the microtask queue are then1, then2 ... then1 is processed (which outputs `then1` and adds `heavystuff` to the microtask queue, behind then2, therefore the console.log of then2 happens, which adds `then21` to the queue before heavystuff executes ... once heavystuff finishes (here is the pause), adding `then11` to the queue, then `then21` is output, and then `then11` is output

Comment: if you want a deeper understanding, this video https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0?t=24m00s does a decent job

Comment: So I guess then1 and then2 are "in the same loop" as you wrote before. And then the results are added to the queue one by one. So one per loop to stay in that language. Meaning nth elements are not in the same loop...but as you said...that really doesn't matter that much...just for clarification

Answer (score 0):

This is because your method `test` returns `promise` variable, that is not the same as result returned by `catch` in it, so when you call `.test()`, it will not wait the whole chain inside `test`.

If you change

```
promise
    .then(()=>console.log("then1"))
    .then(()=>this.simulateHeavyStuff(2000))
    .then(()=>console.log("then11"))
    .catch(console.error)
```

to

```
promise = promise
    .then(()=>console.log("then1"))
    .then(()=>this.simulateHeavyStuff(2000))
    .then(()=>console.log("then11"))
    .catch(console.error)
```

it will work as you expected.

Comment: Thanks! No, it's really ok for my use case to add those callbacks in parallel. So I don't need the second chain to be added after the first. I just did not get the determinism behind the order at first.

Answer (score -1):

The answer seems to be that you—probably by mistake—created two promises (since `.then` creates a **new** promise object based on the previous one, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining)). Have a look at the comments below:

```
test(): Promise<void> {
  // this creates the base promise "A"
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
    });
  // this creates promise "A1" by adding a chain of operations to "A"
  // you are not returning it however
  promise
    .then(()=>console.log("then11"))
    .then(()=>console.log("then12"))
    .then(()=>this.simulateHeavyStuff(2000))
    .then(()=>console.log("then14"))
    .catch(console.error)

  // this returns "A" (not "A1")
    return promise;

}



// this creates promise "A2"
t.test()
  .then(()=>console.log("then2"))
  .then(()=>console.log("then21"))
  .catch(console.error)
```

When you run the code snippet you will see that the processing of both promises seems to be done fully deterministically by the [round-robin principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling) (meaning that the promises are executed in turn for every `.then` operation step). The sequence is

> "A1" -> "A2" -> "A1" ...

```js
class Test {

    simulateHeavyStuff(time){
        // console.log("-"+time+"-");
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        var end = start;
        while(end < start + time) {
            end = new Date().getTime();
        }
        console.log('then13 (heavy stuff)');
    }

    test() {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
        });

        // ##### ADDING CHAIN 1 #####
        promise
        .then(()=>console.log("then11"))
        .then(()=>console.log("then12"))
        .then(()=>this.simulateHeavyStuff(2000))
        .then(()=>console.log("then14"))
        .catch(console.error)
        
        return promise;

    }

}

let t = new Test();

// ##### ADDING CHAIN 2 #####
t.test()
.then(()=>console.log('then21'))
.then(()=>console.log('then22'))
.then(()=>console.log('then23'))
.catch(console.error)
```

In your case—where the execution steps are all fully synchronous—the program is being executed deterministically: i.e. the *i*-th chained `.then` operation of promise "A1" precedes the *i*-th chained `.then` operation of "A2"; and the *i+1* chained `.then` operation of promise "A1" follows the *i*-th chained `.then` operation of promise "A2".

The [ECMA Script 2015 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen) seems to confirm this behavior since the `.then` pools are supposed to queued in a job queue.

Comment: Thanks! I created those two promises on purpose. I want a class to add something to the "then queue" of A (creating A1) and the outer code (the one that calls that class) use the same promise (A) the way it wants (in the test example creating A2).

Regarding the queue see my answer that I wrote in parallel to yours about Microtasks and have a look at the video. It nicely explains the different queuing behaviors of the 3 stacks (Tasks, Animation Callbacks, Microtasks).
Here is the video at the right time: https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0?t=1656

Comment: "*the i-th chained .then operation of promise "A1" will always precede the i-th chained .then operation of "A2"; and the i+1 chained .then operation of promise "A1" must follow the i-th chained .then operation of promise "A2".*" - Nope, not at all. If A1 and A2 are two independent promises, they may resolve at any time  and in any order.

Comment: @Bergi Source? Also, keep in mind that I was talking about the specific case (where the execution steps are synchronous by themselves) and about the execution steps rather then the whole promises.

Comment: @FK82 `const logger = m => () => console.log(m); const delay = t => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, t)); const a = Promise.resolve(); a.then(Math.random).then(delay).then(logger("a1")); a.then(Math.random).then(delay).then(logger("a2"));`

Comment: @FK82 Ah, yes, for synchronous execution steps it might be true for the particular promise scheduler, but you mentioned "synchronous" nowhere in your answer

Comment: @Bergi There is no timeout in the original question. I think you are overlooking that this is a special case.